# When button is clicked first time, why Tom is getting rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const DetailsPage = props => {
  const [user, setData] = useState("Harry");
  const [isShow, setShow] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounted");
    setShow(true);
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount");
    };
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setData("Tom");
          console.log(user);
          setShow(false);
        }}
      >
        {isShow ? <>{user}</> : <>""</>}
      </button>
      {user}
    </div>
  );
};
export default DetailsPage;
```

When I click on button (after component is rendered on screen), it is showing Tom as button value. Can someone explain me how this code is working?(Why Tom is appearing, why not ""(empty string))

Comment: Regarding `console.log("Mounted");` please be mindful that `useEffect` is triggered after render method and not exactly when the component mounts, unlike `componentDidMount` that is triggered when actually mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `setData` and `setShow` are asynchronous methods.
When you call `setData("Tom")`, `user` will be updated and `useEffect` will be triggered as you passed `user` as a dependency.
But this useEffect triggering will be slightly delayed comparing with the `setShow` inside the onClick, because `setData` is the asynchronous methods.

So, method order is

- setData("Tom")
- setShow(false)
- useEffect.

In the last useEffect, it is calling `setShow(true)`, that's why "Tom" is rendered.

Comment: yeah that last setShow(true) will re-render the component, then Harry should be printed right?

Comment: you already call setData("Tom") inside onClick, so Tom will be printed once you click the button

Comment: So it's like, it is storing the value Tom somewhere(some hidden data-store) and on rendering it is taking that value (Tom). Is it correct?

Comment: Tom is stored in the `data` state after `setData("Tom")` and setShow(true) will make the `isShow` true, so `{isShow ? <>{user}</> : <>""</>}` will render `user` which is "Tom"

Comment: Ok, got it, that's a really good explanation - Thanks. Finally done

Comment: Yes, but what will be the explanation when I click it 2nd time, its showing ""  (empty string) ?

Comment: in the second click, even you call setData("Tom"), useEffect won't be triggered because `data` is already Tom, and it's not updated. so `setShow(false);` will be called, and finally `isShow`  will be false, so {isShow ? <>{user}</> : <>""</>} will render empty string.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, then set the user as Tom and set the show to `false`. when changing your user data `useEffect` function will call. then inside your `useEffect`, set show to `true` again and render value.

Comment: yeah that last setShow(true) will re-render the component, then Harry should be printed right?

Comment: Then set user "Harry" to "Tom"

Comment: What about a second click, it becomes "", empty string - why is it so?